# Is there such a thing as a firewire to usb 2 converter, for older Macs?

Tags: mac, usb, firewire, usb-2

A friend has an old [iLamp iMac](http://apple-history.com/?page=gallery&model=imac_early_2003&sort=date&performa=off&order=ASC), which only has USB 1. It’s got a FireWire 400 port though.

To make it less painful getting video etc. on and off his iPhone 4, it’d be great if he could get USB 2 working on his machine (which he’d really like to avoid upgrading for now to save money).

Is there such a thing as a FireWire 400 to USB 2 converter? Maybe something like [this](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=513590)? (Just not discontinued.)

Comment: Actually, USB 2 is backwards compatible to USB 1. It should just be slower. Nothing bad can happen if he tries to connect the phone to the computer. At worst, nothing will happen.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Some products refuse to work on 12mbps USB 1 because it's just too darn slow to provide a sensible user experience.

Comment: @Spiff Never seen such a product before. Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: @AndrejaKo — aha! The iPhone 4 actually does work on USB 1, he was confused about what his problem was. (Not to say there aren’t any products that refuse to work on USB 1. I’ve never seen one personally, but I’m sure they could exist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, doesn’t look like there is such a thing:

- http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-firewire-to-usb-adapter.htm
- http://forums.macnn.com/69/mac-notebooks/359501/help-i-need-firewire-400-usb/
- http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1914267&tstart=0